# Moving WooCommerce Product Image Metabox to Top

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta-boxes

I am trying to move the WooCommerce Featured Product Image metabox to the top. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
function meta_box_position() {
remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'post', 'side' );
add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image'),  'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high');

}
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'meta_box_position');
```

Is there something special I need to do for WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

I changed 'post' to 'product' and it worked.

```
function meta_box_position() {
remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'product', 'side' );
add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Product Image'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'product', 'side', 'high');

}
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'meta_box_position');
```